Ошибка в python: 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 61: invalid continuation byte' при использовании psycopg2
у меня возникла проблему, которую я не понимаю как решить, в ниже представленном коде я пытаюсь создать таблицу в базе данных psql с помощью psycopg2, на бумаге, этот код должен создавать отдельную таблицу, но на деле он выводит такую вот ошибку: 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 61: invalid continuation byte'
Я немного порылся в интернете, уловил суть, это из-за того, что разная кодировка и я это помню, что у windows-а нашего великого не utf-8, но все решение этой проблемы были связаны с open(), там где можно указать способ кодировки (encoding), в этом же файле я просто не представляю как это сделать, хотелось бы объяснение по работе этой системы и конечно же решения.
import psycopg2
from config import host, user, password, db_name

connection = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname=db_name,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        host=host
    )

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE client('
                       'client_id INT PRIMARY KEY,'
                       'first_name VARCHAR(50),'
                       'second_name VARCHAR(50),'
                       'third_name VARCHAR(50),'
                       'age INT,'
                       'card_number INT,'
                       'gender VARCHAR(10),'
                       'cash_balance DECIMAL(8, 2))')

    connection.commit()
except Exception as _ex:
    print('Connection error', _ex)
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()

Изменено: Вот скрин с PgAdmin-а, и я не понимаю, что это, но вдруг это что-то важное (Я переустановил PostgreSQL)

А пробовали открыть файл с помощью with open() с явно указанной кодировкой windows-1251?

with open('file_name', encoding='windows-1251') as f:

Да, это невозможно, ведь мы создаём соединение с базой данных, и with() в данном случае используется чисто для того, что бы после метода execute, в блоке finally не закрывать cursor в ручную, ничего же общего с файлами это не имеет, да и даже если засунуть open в with connection.cursor() as cursor: то далее метод execute просто начинает ругаться, да и в целом, опять же, это же (connection.cursor()) не файл, как я понимаю, так же было предположение, что бы просто сделать переменную cursor = connection.cursor(), и потом использовать execute и закрывать вручную курсор - но и это не сработало

Так же я узнал, что это могло было бы быть из-за того, что мы импортируем данные для коннекта с БД с другого файла, что и могло создавать такую проблему, поэтому я попробовал явно указать db_name, user, password и host, а не через переменные - всё, что из этого вышло - ошибка с другим номером: ''utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 55: invalid continuation byte'

При этом, любой код из интернета, даже самый простой, так же не работает, что за? У меня одно предположение - неправильные входные данные для коннекта с базой данных, точнее, даже создать БД не могу, я не понимаю

Настройки кодировки БД смотрели?
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;

Возможно, проблема в самом запросе к базе данных. Может быть, из-за вашей формы запроса ломается его структура.
Я бы предложил сделать так:
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE client(
                    client_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                    first_name VARCHAR(50),
                    second_name VARCHAR(50),
                    third_name VARCHAR(50),
                    age INT,
                    card_number INT,
                    gender VARCHAR(10),
                    cash_balance DECIMAL(8, 2)
                )
            ''')

Можно еще проверить кодировку самой базы данных:
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;

После чего можно явно указать ее в коде:
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=db_name,
    user=user,
    password=password,
    host=host,
    options="-c client_encoding=UTF8"
)

Можно еще все это завернуть в двойной try, чтобы отловить все ошибки.

Здравствуйте, да, я думал над запросом и переписал его, нет - это не влияет на ошибку, что так, что так одно и тоже, попробовал добавить options, как вы указали - нет, это тоже не сработало, ошибки почему то не ловит. при этом блок exepct даже не работает как задумывалось
Стоит еще сказать, что я пробовал самый простейший запрос к БД, который тоже не сработал, у меня есть только одно предположение - это что-то с данными, которые я ввожу в connect, либо они не правильные, либо как то не правильно читаются python-ом

Вот код, который я вставлял в программу и который так же не работал:
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="metanit", user="postgres", password="240696518", host="127.0.0.1")
cursor = conn.cursor()
создаем таблицу people
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE people (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50),  age INTEGER)")
поддверждаем транзакцию
conn.commit()
print("Таблица people успешно создана")
cursor.close()
conn.close()

И так, входе всего разбирательства у меня получилось создать БД этим способом
Вывод таков: Похоже, что какие-либо данные, может быть пароль, может быть юзер БД были введены неверно, из-за этого пайтон не мог подключиться к БД и выводило такую вот ошибку
Как я это пофиксил: Просто полностью переустановил БД, поставил новый пароль и юзера, которых сохранил и ввёл их для коннекта, новая таблица появилась в pgAdmin-е
Что бы у вас такого не случилось - проверяйте, правильные ли вы данные вводите для коннекта с базой данных
